# I cannot find my imported OBJ

Tags: import

So basically I imported an OBJ from a game (Roblox) and it has various parts, but it does not go where I want it to go when I import it.

It is in Blender and its visible I just cannot find it. Anyway to teleport to an object or teleport a object to you?

Comment: *"It is in Blender and its visible I just cannot find it"* how is that? *"teleport to an object"* use Numpad period button. *"teleport a object to you"* use Shift+S > Selection To cursor. Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51685/centre-every-object-in-relation-to-each-other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to see anything after importing .obj file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31766/unable-to-see-anything-after-importing-obj-file) or [Why when importing an obj file nothing appears even when zooming?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89710/why-when-importing-an-obj-file-nothing-appears-even-when-zooming/89720#89720)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88007/imported-obj-shows-too-small

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89710/why-when-importing-an-obj-file-nothing-appears-even-when-zooming/89720#89720 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36302/obj-file-not-displayed-properly/36303#36303

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the objects then deselect camera and lamp, after that press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to set your 3d cursor to the center, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then *Selection to Cursor (Offset)* 
This should place your objects in the center of your 3d scene.

Comment: `A` selects or deselects **all** regardless of object type

Comment: I just corrected the words, thanks for the comment